# how to convert audio to ".WAV" format on upload

Tags: php, android, file-upload, wav, audio-recording

I am developing one application where the users can upload audio files to the server by

using  any android version in the mobile. By using in built android voice recorder they can

create only `.amr` format of the audio. But I need audio in the `.wav` format  for some

telephonic use at the server side .

Is there any way in android to create `.wav` format in built android voice recorder

or at the server end is it possible convert any audio file format to `.wav` using `PHP`.

Any help would be thanksfull.

Comment: Rather than setting up a server to convert AMR->WAV, wouldn't it be easier to just do the recording in your app? I.e. use the AudioRecord class to record PCM data, add a WAV header to that, and you're done.

Comment: Whatever you choose to do the job don't do it "on upload". Queue the conversion. I recommend perfect service called Gearman for that job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be using FFMPEG as an php extension or you could run ffmpeg directly for converting. The simple way to do using php is:

```
<?php exec(ffmpeg -i audio.amr testwav.wav) ?>
```

But you may encounter some difficulties. So you should add some parameters. You could use "-ar" to set audio sampling rate (in Hz), "-ab" to set audio bit rate (in bits/s) and etc. Below is the sample:

```
<?php exec("ffmpeg -i audio.amr -ar 22050 -ab 32 -map_meta_data audio.wav:audio.amr audio.wav"); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest converting on the server-side to save the bandwidth in transit from an uncompressed file.

You can use [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to do the conversion for you.

Comment: Another benefit of doing the conversion server-side is that if your format requirements change, you don't need to publish a new version of your application.

Answer (score 0):

i think PHP is the best option, you can use [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/), and take a look at these pages:

1. http://wiki.dreamhost.com/FFmpeg
2. http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Php-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `FFMPEG` on an `Android` device. It may be a tricky setup (some `NDK` configurations required), but this has been simplified greatly by `JavaCV` (available [here](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use 3rd party online format conversion API to do the job, but if you have a server not limited on resources you can go to `FFMPEG` as suggested by Brad.
You could use online API like [online-convert](http://api.online-convert.com/) or find one matches you the best.